# Why is downloading a big file frequently truncated by browser(http)?

Tags: browser, download

I'm downloading a linux image [here](http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/13/Live/i686/Fedora-13-i686-Live.iso), its size is `675MB`

But the browser always finishes downloading at only `10MB`

This kind of thing doesn't happen if I use a dedicated tool for downloading,

why it's so weak in browser?

Comment: Which browser, which OS? (I never have such problems.)

Comment: Which browser?  Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: I've met this problem in all browsers so far,haven't you guys ever met this problem?

Comment: No. It is a problem only at you I guess. What operating system, arch, what system, net, etc? MOAR INFO!!!!111

Comment: I just tried downloading from the link in Firefox, and it works nicely and supports resuming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your internet connection must be dying out in between. Most browsers can't handle resuming downloads well and hence your download dies out. Using a download manager will help you resume. If you are behind a proxy server, you might face such problems too.

Comment: If by "most" you mean "IE"...

Comment: lol .. actually since I use internet in college behind a proxy server i face similar problems with firefox and chrome too :)